# Change css element style with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I want to change the css element style using Python Selenium while doing automation to increase the height of the page. The html of the element is as follows:

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:150px;">
```

I know that I can use something like the code below to do this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('id name').style.height = '2000px';")
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementByClassName('class name').style.height = '2000px';")
```

But there is no `id` or `class` in the HTML (there's only `style`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no `ID` or `class` is present then please use `CSS`

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementByCss('div[style='overflow-y:scroll']').style.height = '2000px';")
```

But you should check in HTML DOM for the mentioned CSS :

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `CSS` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

CSS you should check :

```
div[style='overflow-y:scroll']
```

or

```
div[style='overflow-y:scroll'][sytle$='height:150px;']
```

or

```
div[style='overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:150px;']
```

Whichever has the unique entry put that in `execute_script` and you should be good to go after that.

**Alternate way to do**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[style='overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:150px;']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:2000px;')", element)
```